# Помещаю функцию в цикл - выдаёт Fatal'ный Eггог

Tags: php

Есть такой вот код:
(он прекрасно работает - получает циферки из файла ЦБРФ)
Но как только я его засовываю в `for` для формирования массива данных, он выдаёт `Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_content()`
Почему так?
P.S. `for` делаю обычно: `for ($t=0; $t<90; $t++){[код][сборка массива]}`

```
  $content = get_content(); 

  $pattern = "#<Valute ID=\"([^\"]+)[^>]+>[^>]+>([^<]+)[^>]+>[^>]+>[^>]+>[^>]+>[^>]+>[^>]+>([^<]+)[^>]+>[^>]+>([^<]+)#i"; 

  preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER); 
  $dollar = ""; 
  $euro = ""; 
  foreach($out as $cur) 
  { 
    if($cur[2] == 840) $dollar = round(str_replace(",",".",$cur[4]), 2);  //c округлением до сотых
    if($cur[2] == 978) $euro = round(str_replace(",",".",$cur[4]), 2);
  } 
  function get_content() 
  { 
    // Формирование дат 

    $date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("-".$t." days"));  
    // Формируем ссылку 
    $link = "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=$date"; 
    // Загружаем HTML-страницу 
    $fd = fopen($link, "r"); 
    $text=""; 
    if (!$fd) echo "Запрашиваемая страница не найдена"; 
    else 
    { 
      // Чтение содержимого файла в переменную $text 
      while (!feof ($fd)) $text .= fgets($fd, 4096); 
    } 
    // Закрыть открытый файловый дескриптор 
    fclose ($fd); 
    return $text;
```

---

[см. **этот пример** в php-песочнице [...]](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IpHNd0)

Comment: Когда заворачиваете в цикл, `get_content()` ставите вне цикла?

Comment: Функцию объявите в начале файла и вне цикла создаваемого.

Comment: выложите код, в котором ошибка

Comment: Возьмите функцию `get_content()` полностью от `function get_сontent() {` до закрывающего `}`, и перенесите вне цикла. Там начинают вываливаться другие ошибки, но они кажется больше к содержимому...

Comment: @cyadvert Так как же тогда `$link = "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=$date"; ` ведь это формируется ссылка в зависимости от количества итераций цикла. Это чтение файла. т.е. каждую итерацию - другой файл.

Comment: @korytoff так в низу же `см. этот пример в php-песочнице [...]`

Comment: Значит передавайте `$date` в функцию как параметр. Иначе Вы заставляете код 90 раз создавать функцию, а это невозможно по законам программирования

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функцию то не надо объявлять в цикле 90 раз.

```
function get_content($t) 
  { 
    // Формирование дат 
    //$date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("+4 hours")); 
    $date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("-".$t." days"));  
    // Формируем ссылку 
    $link = "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=$date"; 
    // Загружаем HTML-страницу 
    $fd = fopen($link, "r"); 
    $text=""; 
    if (!$fd) echo "Запрашиваемая страница не найдена"; 
    else 
    { 
      // Чтение содержимого файла в переменную $text 
      while (!feof ($fd)) $text .= fgets($fd, 4096); 
    } 
    // Закрыть открытый файловый дескриптор 
    fclose ($fd); 
    return $text; 
  } 

for ($t=0; $t<90; $t++)

{
 // Получаем текущие курсы валют в rss-формате с сайта www.cbr.ru 
  $content = get_content($t); 
  // Разбираем содержимое, при помощи регулярных выражений 
  $pattern = "#<Valute ID=\"([^\"]+)[^>]+>[^>]+>([^<]+)[^>]+>[^>]+>[^>]+>[^>]+>[^>]+>[^>]+>([^<]+)[^>]+>[^>]+>([^<]+)#i"; 

  preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER); 
  $dollar = ""; 
  $euro = ""; 
  foreach($out as $cur) 
  { 
    if($cur[2] == 840) $dollar = round(str_replace(",",".",$cur[4]), 2);  //c округлением до сотых<em></em>
    if($cur[2] == 978) $euro = round(str_replace(",",".",$cur[4]), 2);
  } 
  //echo "Доллар - ".$dollar."<br>"; 
  //echo "Евро - ".$euro."<br>"; 
  //echo date("---- H:i d/m/Y", strtotime("+4 hours")); 

$dollal_array[$t]=$dollar;
$euro_array[$t]=$euro;

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Заработало!

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сделать несколько перемен.

1. Всю функцию от `function get_content() {` до закрывающего `}` убрать из цикла и поставить в конец файла. Главное - убрать из цикла.
2. Код, вызывающий функцию, поменять на `$content = get_content($t);`. Насколько я понял, единственный параметр, который используется внутри функции, это `$t`...

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.
Главное, что заработало. Скоро будет график курса валют за 3 мес-ца.

Answer (score -2):

Проблема заключается скорее всего в том, что, в момент вызова функции - она не определена, в данном случае описывается после вызова.
Обязательно посмотрите комментарий @korytoff, я считаю, что его ответ полностью решит вашу проблему.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?